# NoMethodError (undefined method) from Private method in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Why can't I use a private method from within my class? How do I fix my code to prevent the error?

```
module CarRegistration
  class Basics < Base

    fields_of_model(:car).each do |attr|
      delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: :car
    end

    private

    car_structure = #array of hashes

    def fields_of_model(model)
      car_structure.select {|record| record[:model] == model}.map{|record| record[:name]}
    end
end
```

### error

> NoMethodError (undefined method `fields_of_model' for
>   CarRegistration::Basics:Class):

Comment: Did you get this sorted out? If you found my answer correct, perhaps mark it as `accepted` for future searchers.

Comment: @jvillian, it worked, just by getting rid of all the private methods. I would have preferred to keep them. I need to review your code in more detail and test again. THANK YOU

Comment: You'll find, with the code I provided, that the `fields_of_model` method is private. The `fields_of_model(:car).each do |attr|` block is not a method and is only run when the class is loaded. So, there's no notion of `public` or `private` for that bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a number of problems going on here.

First, you've defined `fields_of_model` as an instance method, here:

```
def fields_of_model(model)
  car_structure.select {|record| record[:model] == model}.map{|record| record[:name]}
end
```

but you're trying to call it from the class, here:

```
fields_of_model(:car).each do |attr|
  delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: :car
end
```

So, you'll want to make `fields_of_model` a class method, and define it before you call it. Something like:

```
module CarRegistration
  class Basics < Base

    private

    car_structure = #array of hashes

    class << self

      def fields_of_model(model)
        car_structure.select {|record| record[:model] == model}.map{|record| record[:name]}
      end

    end

    fields_of_model(:car).each do |attr|
      delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: :car
    end

end
```

You'll also have problems with that `car_structure` variable, I think, because it'll be out of scope for the class method. So, I think you need to make a class-level instance variable. So, give this a try:

```
module CarRegistration
  class Basics < Base

    @car_structure = #array of hashes

    class << self

      def fields_of_model(model)
        @car_structure.select {|record| record[:model] == model}.map{|record| record[:name]}
      end

      private :fields_of_model

    end

    fields_of_model(:car).each do |attr|
      delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: :car
    end

end
```

Note that I made the class method, `:fields_of_models` private using `private :fields_of_model`.

To demonstrate the whole thing, I ginned up this RSpec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

class Car

  attr_accessor *%w(
    color
    make
    year
  ).freeze

end

module CarRegistration
  class Basic

    @car_structure = [
      {model: :car, name: :color},
      {model: :car, name: :make},
      {model: :car, name: :year}
    ]

    class << self

      def fields_of_model(model)
        @car_structure.select {|record| record[:model] == model}.map{|record| record[:name]}
      end

      private :fields_of_model

    end

      fields_of_model(:car).each do |attr|
        delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: :car
      end

      def car
        @car ||= Car.new 
      end

  end
end

RSpec.describe CarRegistration::Basic do
    it "has :fields_of_model as a private class method" do 
      expect(CarRegistration::Basic.public_methods).not_to include(:fields_of_model)
      expect(CarRegistration::Basic.private_methods).to include(:fields_of_model)
    end
    it "responds to :color and :color=" do
      expect(car_registration).to respond_to(:color)
      expect(car_registration).to respond_to(:color=)
    end
    it "sets and gets attributes on car" do
      expect(car_registration.color).to be_nil
      expect(car_registration.car.color).to be_nil
      car_registration.color = :red
      expect(car_registration.car.color).to eq(:red)
      expect(car_registration.color).to eq(:red)
      expect(car_registration.instance_variable_get(:@color)).to be_nil 
    end
end

def car_registration
  @car_registration ||= described_class.new
end
```

Which, when run, yields:

```
CarRegistration::Basic
  has :fields_of_model as a private class method
  responds to :color and :color=
  sets and gets attributes on car

Finished in 0.733 seconds (files took 27.84 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures
```

BTW, having this code in your class outside of a `def`-`end` is just fine and not the root of your problem. In fact, it's quite normal.

Also, I will note that [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag) wishes to say:

> I am one of those Ruby Purists who likes to point out that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. I am perfectly fine, though, with using the term *class method* colloquially, **as long as it is fully understood by all parties that it is a colloquial usage**. In other words, if you *know* that there is no such thing as a class method and that the term "class method" is just short for "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of `Class`", then there is no problem. But otherwise, I have only seen it obstruct understanding.

Let it be fully understood by all parties that the term *class method* is used above in its colloquial sense.

Comment: This is an active model class and I see you made everything private. I believe I need my fields_of_model method to be public. How do I resolve this?

Comment: ^ , am I missing something?

Comment: The `fields_of_model` method was private in your original post. It's not clear from your example why the method would be either public or private. Further editing of your question might help clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, my loop of field_of_model is not private

Comment: Are you concerned your delegations will be private? I don't think that will occur. But, I'll edit on how to approach in a bit.

Comment: Added RSpec example. Made `:fields_of_model` private. Faked up a `Car` class because I didn't want to spin up the `Car` and `CarRegistration::Basic` classes as true AR models. Added a `car` method to `CarRegistration::Basic` to mimic a `belongs_to :car` association.

Answer (score -1):

Because you wrote the method **not** in `def`-`end` clause; you should write it like

```
def my_method
  fields_of_model(:car).each do |attr|
    delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: :car
  end
end
```

That is why the error message says `CarRegistration::Basics:Class` as opposed to `CarRegistration::Basics`

Here is a sample code that works.
Usually there is no need to put a class inside `Module`, but if you must for some reason, this is a way.

```
module CarRegistration
  class Basics < Object
    def run(model)
      fields_of_model(model)
    end

    private

    def fields_of_model(model)
      puts model
    end
  end
end

a = CarRegistration::Basics.new
a.run('xyz')  # => 'xyz' is printed.
```

Comment: So I assume there are two solutions, 1) wrap my code with a def-end clause, and somehow call it (how), 2) Make my private methods available to the class. What is the recommended way to do either?

Comment: If I wrap it in a def-end clause I get `undefined method `my_method' for CarRegistration::Basics:Class. and if I set self.my_method, `fields_of_model`, is still undefined method `fields_of_model' for CarRegistration::Basics:Class

Comment: I have edited the post.  It works.  I am not sure why you have put `Class` inside `Module` to make a complex structure, though…

Comment: That's not really going to work because, you see, because the OP is trying to dynamically create getters and setters, which you can't do inside of instance methods. (More accurately, the OP is trying to delegate getters and setters, but the point still holds.)